# WebSphere Portal 6.1 default theme deleted

Tags: themes, websphere-portal

I deleted the chosen default theme in WebSphere Portal 6.1 using the administration pages. Now the portal is themeless. More importantly, the theme selection page in the administration section can no longer be displayed.

How can I set the default theme "externally" (i.e. manually, without the administration pages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to correct this with xmlaccess.  I suggest you export from a working portal the theme configuration back into your broken portal.

Comment: You answer helped solve the problem. Thank you. Could you please update your answer with the following information:

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21260098
https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385592

It might be useful for other people having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Chrisr is right. Here is how to use xmlaccess in little more detail:

To generate a full export of your Portal's configuration, do the following:

1. Copy the file `<Portal_home>/doc/xml-samples/Export.xml` to `<Portal_home>/bin`.
2. Open a terminal or command window. Change directory (cd) to `<Portal_home>/bin`.
3. From the directory `<Portal_home>/bin`, run the following `xmlaccess` command all on one line:

`xmlaccess -user <Portal_admin_user> -password <Portal_admin_password> -url http://<myhost>:<port>/wps/config -in Export.xml -out result.xml`

(from: [IBM How to generate a complete XMLAccess export of a Portal configuration](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21260098))

You might encounter an error `EJPXB0016E Connection refused`. It is because either:

- `localhost` cannot be resolved or
- `-url` option was not supplied

If `localhost` cannot be resolved, open the following file:

```
../wp_profile/ConfigEngine/properties/wkplc_comp.properties
```

and change `XmlAccessHost=localhost` to `XmlAccessHost=hostname.compyname.com`.

(from: [IBM Configuration task fails during XMLAccess with 'EJPXB0016E Connection refused' error](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385592)). I simply forgot the `-url` parameter and didn't have to change that value.

If everything goes well, you should have the `result.xml` file. Use `xmlaccess` again with the `result.xml` to configure the server with default theme deleted:

`xmlaccess -user <Portal_admin_user> -password <Portal_admin_password> -url http://<myhost>:<port>/wps/config -in result.xml`