# Revert the Theme settings in IBM web sphere portal 5.0

Tags: websphere-portal

I am new to this IBM portal 5.0 personilization. 
I have created new theme by copying the already existing theme in IBM Websphere portal 5.0 and named it as Mytheme. And i made this theme as poratl default(This is the mistake i have done). And i verified all pages, that whether all the pages getting reflected. at that time i was able to change the theme default settings to from the existing theme and newly created theme. because i was logged into the portal.

Today i tried to access the portal and it doesn't show me anything in the content area(Portlets are not shown).It is not showing login portlet. so couldn't login as administrator. Not able to change anything..

Could anybody help me to resolve this issue. i have to revert my changes. All configurations are stored in Oracle DB.

Any idea to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use xmlAccess to correct your problem. This other question looks offer a solution for you.

[WebSphere Portal 6.1 default theme deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184976/websphere-portal-6-1-default-theme-deleted)

Comment: Yes i have exported the configurations. I haven't deleted theme.. but i have copied the existing working theme and renamed and set as default theme for the portal.. how could we change the default theme from xmlaccess?

Comment: In the export of the portal see if there is an attribute or element that will set the default theme. Use this to set the default theme for the portal back to the original default theme. If xmlAccess doesn't have it, you can see if there is a configEngine task to set the default theme.

Comment: We are using DB for this portal. are the settings saved in Db? will that help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: It could be in the DB, but as far as I know, directly updating the database is unsupported by IBM and I don't have any suggestions on how to do it that way.

Comment: Nick, I tried to export the attributes and elements using xmlAccess. I couldn't find any useful info to resolve the problem. I don't know how to do with configEngine. Could u plz help me.